# Which of the following are true for a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: this is the question]

I'm sure that A,C, and F are true, but the system is still saying I'm incorrect. Where am I going wrong here?

edit: I chose B and the system said I was correct.

Comment: Also (B) is correct

Comment: Everything is correct, except D and E.

Comment: @Roland Didn't think about that one, thanks!

Comment: Ed and Roland: $T$ is assumed to be **orthogonal**.

Comment: Orthogonal linear transformations are invertible. Fixed!